# Onsen UI show modal until page is completely loaded

Tags: onsen-ui

I am trying to show the modal dialog while my page is being loaded. Right now I show the modal before the page push (e.g. app.navi.pushPage( 'detail.html' ) ). In the page init i have to go out and get some data from a third party API, and display it in a list. Once the request is complete and the list is populated I hide the modal.

The issue is that the modal is actually being hidden before the transition starts. Any ideas on how I can hide the modal once the transition is complete and the DOM is loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here there is an example that hides the modal after 2 seconds: http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#UsingModal

In your case I guess you are using an HTTP request or something similar to access the third party API, so it's necessary to hide the modal after preparing all the data in the callback of the request:

```
$http.get('/third/party/API').
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available

  myItemList = data[...];

  ... // refresh view, pushPage or whatever you need to prepare

  modal.hide();

}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // Handle errors in request
});
```

Hope it helps!